# Powerpoint curtain 'closing' transition effect workaround

Tags: vba, powerpoint, transition

In MS Powerpoint 2016(maybe 2013) or above, there is a transition effect which opens the slide with a curtain.
The only way to make the curtain close is to pressing 'P' key (or 'BackSpace', PgUp  keys).
I know there are users' voices to request this closing curtain effect ( https://powerpoint.uservoice.com/forums/288949-powerpoint-for-windows-desktop-application/suggestions/15570894-please-make-a-curtain-closing-transition-in-powerp )

So I thought about how to accomplish this.
I figured out that if I send those 'Back' keys(P, BackSpace or PgUp) on the next slide of the transition slide, it would be possible to make it close the curtain.

Here I suppose the transition effect is on slide #2. And I added a closing button(shape) on the last slide. If the presenter presses the 'close' button on the last slide, it goes like this:
1. move to slide #2 where the curtain effect is applied 
2. send a(ny) key to stop the previous transition effect.
3. wait for a second
4. send a real BackSpace key(or 'P', 'PgUp' key)
5. Finally, here comes the closing curtain effect.

Following is the macro code that I wrote.

```
Sub CloseCurtain()

    SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide 2

    'Send any key
    SendKeys "{PGUP}"   'make the transition effect(opening curtain) finish

    'wait for 1 second
    Wait = Timer
    Do While Timer < Wait + 1
        DoEvents
    Loop

    SendKeys "{PGUP}"   'move to the previous slide and close the curtain
    'SendKeys "{BS}" "{P}" "{UP}" is the same

End Sub
```

Do you have any suggestion or better ideas about this?